# solace message Id not viewed in solAdmin

Tags: solace, solace-mq

I have published a message in the solace interface and got the messageId generated for that.

From SolAdmin, When I inspect the queue, I can able to see one new messages received, but the message id which generated is not same.

```
TextMessage txtMsg = jmsSession.createTextMessage();
messageID = txtMsg.getJMSMessageID();
```

The above messageID generated the output as 
ID:2eaaf46d-b9ff-4aeb-a385-fbc2e6cced0a:1:1:1-1

But in SolAdmin, the message shows as 5985824677

Answer (score 1):

The "Message ID" that is shown in the endpoints tab of SolAdmin is internal to the Solace Message Broker and is not equivalent to the "JMS Message ID".

You can use it for operations such as deleting some messages via the CLI or SEMP.
For example:

```
solace(admin/message-spool)# delete-messages queue my_sample_queue message 123456789 to 123456790
```

There's no way to display the JMS Message ID in SolAdmin.
Instead, you will need to make use of a queue browser to browse messages in the queue.

This can be a custom application that you write, [sdkperf](https://docs.solace.com/SDKPerf/SDKPerf.htm) (use the -qb and -md flags), or a third party graphical JMS queue browser such as [HermesJMS](https://docs.solace.com/Developer-Tools/Integration-Guides/Hermes-Jms.htm).

Comment: You could also use JMSToolBox for this (FYI I'm the author of JMSToolBox...): https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox